# File name autocomplete with dropdown

Tags: company-mode, auto-complete-mode, abbrev, hippie-expand

I like vim's tabcomplete feature - filename completion for its dropdown choices. Like this vi popdown,

[image]

I use `hippie-expand` with functions, `try-complete-file-name-partially try-complete-file-name`. It shows one option at a time not all the options with a drop-down. It consumes lot of time, calling `hippie-expand` for each and every wrong completion.

Is there any elisp library that has filepath autocompletion with dropdowns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [filename completion using company-mode](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3654/filename-completion-using-company-mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[company-mode](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode) has a [files backend](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/blob/master/company-files.el):

[image]

Comment: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3654/filename-completion-using-company-mode

Answer (score 2):

[auto-complete](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete) also has this feature, via its built-in *(ac-source-filename)* backend.  In addition, for c/c++, there is *auto-complete-c-headers*, see https://github.com/mooz/auto-complete-c-headers. Here is a screenshot of the latter: 
[image: drop-down-for-c-headers]